# Помогите понять как реализовать взаимодействие двух обьектов разных классов

Tags: java, объекты

Суть в чём: Пытаюсь немного поэксперементировать, и поделать задачки не из книг, а из головы(ибо сейчас фокус внимания очень расплывчат, и больший эфект будет от творчества чем от зубрежки)
Пытаюсь реализовать метод fight который определял бы, у которого из двух обьектов бойцов лучшие характеристики.И не могу ни понять, ни найти в гугле(не могу понять что именно гуглить).
как обьявить переменные в этом методе, чтобы он заработал.
собственно сам код:

```
public class TestoPromo {




public static void main(String[] args) {
    class Human {
        String name;
        int str;
        int agi;
        int vit;

        public Human() {
        }

        public Human(String name, int str, int agi, int vit) {
            this.name = name;
            this.str = str;
            this.agi = agi;
            this.vit = vit;

        }
    }
    class Orc {
        String name;
        int str;
        int agi;
        int vit;

        public Orc() {
        }

        public Orc(String name, int str, int agi, int vit) {
            this.name = name;
            this.str = str;
            this.agi = agi;
            this.vit = vit;

        }
    }
    Human gladiatorH1 = new Human("Гавриил",10,10,10);
    Orc gladiatorO1 = new Orc("Ибрагим",12,7,11);
    int humanScore=0;
    int orcScore=0;

    public int fight( orcGlad ; humanGlad ){//не могу понять что писать в этих скобках.

        /*Здесь я выясняю победит орк, человек, или будет ничья*/
        if (orcGlad.str+orcGlad.agi+orcGlad.vit>humanGlad.str+humanGlad.agi+humanGlad.vit)
            orcScore++;
        if (orcGlad.str+orcGlad.agi+orcGlad.vit<humanGlad.str+humanGlad.agi+humanGlad.vit)
            humanScore++;


    }
    System.out.println("Текущий счет: люди "+humanScore+" Орки: "+orcScore);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас очень странный код, классы и метод находятся не там где нужно:

```
    public class TestoPromo {
        static int humanScore = 0;
        static int orcScore = 0;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Human gladiatorH1 = new Human("Гавриил", 10, 10, 10);
            Orc gladiatorO1 = new Orc("Ибрагим", 12, 7, 11);
            fight(gladiatorO1, gladiatorH1);
            System.out.println("Текущий счет: люди " + humanScore + " Орки: " + orcScore);
        }

        public static void fight(Orc orcGlad, Human humanGlad) {//не могу понять что писать в этих скобках.
            /*Здесь я выясняю победит орк, человек, или будет ничья*/
            if (orcGlad.str + orcGlad.agi + orcGlad.vit > humanGlad.str + humanGlad.agi + humanGlad.vit)
                orcScore++;
            if (orcGlad.str + orcGlad.agi + orcGlad.vit < humanGlad.str + humanGlad.agi + humanGlad.vit)
                humanScore++;
        }
    }

    class Human {
        String name;
        int str;
        int agi;
        int vit;

        public Human() {
        }

        public Human(String name, int str, int agi, int vit) {
            this.name = name;
            this.str = str;
            this.agi = agi;
            this.vit = vit;

        }
    }

    class Orc {
        String name;
        int str;
        int agi;
        int vit;

        public Orc() {
        }

        public Orc(String name, int str, int agi, int vit) {
            this.name = name;
            this.str = str;
            this.agi = agi;
            this.vit = vit;

        }
    }
```

Откорректировал Ваш пример.
После выполнения счет 0:0.

оффтоп: как мне кажется, сравнение суммой не очень удачно, так как нужно учитывать коэффициенты параметров.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ и коментарий). Сравнение с суммой чисто для проверки работоспособности, зависимость от коиф. параметров буду делать дальше оп плану)))